# How to get keyboard with Next, Previous and Done Button?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-keypad

I want to have a keyboard which has a Next,Previous and Done button on top of it.

I have seen that in many apps.

Especially where there are forms to be filled.

[image]

I want to achieve something similar to above keyboard

How can I get that?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You'll find the answer on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard). I checked the iOS Library and the [inputAccessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView) of a UITextField is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Or it can be done using storyboard like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41546987/1151916)

Answer (score 25):

I just created a class called [`BSKeyboardControls`](https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls) which makes it very easy to add the controls to a keyboard. The class, instructions and example code can be found [here at GitHub](https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls).

The controls works for text fields and text views and are optimized for both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Just now discovering BSkeyboardControls and love it!  Need it to work with a UIDatePicker instead of a textfield.  Any sample code for this?

Answer (score 19):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing: (UITextField *)textField 

{
     UIToolbar * keyboardToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

    keyboardToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [keyboardToolBar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(previousTextField)],

                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextTextField)],
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)],
                                nil]];
    textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar;

}



- (void)nextTextField {


    if (textField1) {

        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];

    }

}

-(void)previousTextField
{

    if (textField2) {
        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
        [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }


}

-(void)resignKeyboard {

    [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textField2 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea/concept...I'll just need to make some changes.

Comment: i want to this code for 9 textfield so i do this   if (textField1) {

        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];

    } 9 times for differnt textfield but its not working why?

Answer (score 5):

I have a utility class that basically does this for you.

https://github.com/kalvish21/CustomKeyboard

The idea is very simple. You have to add an accessory tool bar with bar button items on it. There's a delegate which defines where what that button will do.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

This is the best keyboard handler I have seen so far. Very excellent way to manage Text inputs.

Some of its features 
1) ZERO LINE OF CODE

2) Works Automatically

3) No More UIScrollView

4) No More Subclasses

5) No More Manual Work

6) No More #imports

Comment: This repo is a year out of date. Use the repo its forked from, https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom control which is placed directly above the keyboard. I think a UIToolbar can be used for that.

Previous and next passes around the firstResponder of the textFields and Done will do the resign as well as hide the toolbar.

To match the keyboard animation have a look at [this code](http://snipplr.com/view/51724/iphone-slide-view-up-and-down-to-match-keyboard-appearing-and-disappearing/) I found or at SO: ["What is the iPhone's default keyboard animation rate?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419221/what-is-the-iphones-default-keyboard-animation-rate)

Comment: Yeah I tried something similar but when I click in TextBox then Toolbar appears immediately and keyboard appears from below so it looks as seperate.it is not in sync while getting displayed. It does look seperate. I want that both keyboard and toolbar should come together from bottom of the screen. What should I do?

Comment: Use an animation block matching the keyboad.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am newbie into animation. How to use the animation block matching with keyboard?

Comment: Have a look at Apple's [Animation Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/AnimationGuide/Articles/TimingAnimations.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [repository](https://github.com/wzbozon/DKKeyboardView) with an implementation of this feature that works on iPhone/iPad in all orientations and highly customizable.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, it's the [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview) that you're looking for.

I would like to add an alternative way here, by using this cocoapods:

pod '[UITextField-Navigation](https://github.com/T-Pham/UITextField-Navigation)'

All `UITextField`s will have two additional properties: `nextTextField` and `previousTextField`. You can then simply connect the `nextTextField` in the Interface Builder and the Previous, Next and Done buttons are added automatically for you, all functional, no more code is needed, no subclassing.

You can also customize the UI, add more buttons, etc as you want to.

[image]
[image]