# Unable to call UIKeyboardNotifications

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitextfield, uitextview

I have one textfield and textview in the view. I want to show toolbar on keyboard when my editing text in textView but I don't want to show toolbar while editing textField. I'm using below code:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
               name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
               name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
 return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                              object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                              object:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

My problem is when user trying to edit textfield and directly start editing textView we are not able to show toolBar for it then? How can I show toolbar on keyboard for such situation?

Comment: btw, why are you calling `viewWillAppear` method in your `textViewShouldBeginEditing` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's explained before on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591792/how-to-get-keyboard-with-next-previous-and-done-button). `UITextField` and `UITextView` has a property `inputAccessoryView` for >iOS3.2, you can set any view you want, and it appears at the top of the keyboard. So, you don't need to use `UINotificationCenter`. Here is the code to accomplish what you want.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar =[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,320,30)];
    keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
 
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flex,barButtonItem, nil];
    [keyboardToolbar setItems:items];
    self.textView.inputAccessoryView =keyboardToolbar;
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

All you need to do is set `inputAccessoryView` for your `UITextView`, so for  `UITextField` default keyboard will appear.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this delegate method to retrieve keyboard notification for UITextField or UITextView

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //self.keyboardNotification = notification; //store notification and process on text begin delegate method. 
}
```

Comment: Yes I have implemented this method but even this delegate method is not getting called when user switch from textField to textView directly as keyboard is already shown.

Comment: where did you set `delegate`? check with your xib or `self.textView.delegate = self `

Comment: thanks mani... that i was forget to add but inputAccessoryView help my problem and it also help me to optimise my code.

Answer (score 0):

You know already that you should use inputAccessoryView, but here is why your code does not work:

`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` will be posted after `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` has returned.

This is because you can cancel the editing by returning NO from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` , and in this case there should be no `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.

Don't remove the notification in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`. Otherwise you are no longer observing this notification when it is posted.

If you add the notifications in `viewWillAppear:`, remove them in `viewWillDisappear:`.