# How to get keyboard with Next, Previous and Done buttons at the top of keyboard in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

In my application, I want to provide the functionality similar to Next, Previous and Done button at the top of keyboard. It is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591792/how-to-get-keyboard-with-next-previous-and-done-button)

[image]

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

I do not want to exactly implement the next,previous and done options. But using this three button click, I want to make three separate web service calls and fetch the results. Like, Active,Inactive and All kind of filters.

Comment: tell us what have you done in your app to implement this? This type of requirement was posted on either elance.com or odesk.com by a Chinese.

Comment: Did you find any solution to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Android way would be to provide an input method action with [`imeOptions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions). With the standard keyboard this will change the bottom right virtual keyboard button to the specified action. There's little point in trying to mimic iOS input behavior with the buttons above.

Comment: imeOptions is good.But  I do not want to exactly implement the next and previous options. But using this three button click, I want to make three separate web service calls and fetch the results. Like, Active/ Inactive and All these kind of filters.

Comment: You should only have input-related actions with the input as there's no reason to assume a vkb is used for input. Put other actions e.g. in your main layout.

Comment: @laalto This type of requirement was posted on either elance.com or odesk.com by a Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to just put the layout above the keyboard,so as to stop next,previous,etc button when keyboard is displayed.
If so,you can try adding below code inside your activity in android manifest,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

If you are looking for something else,then please show your xml code of the same.