# Navigation using return button in apple keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have more than one text field in my view controller how can i navigate from one to another using the return button in the IOS keyboard.

Comment: you can use tag for this

Comment: @BHASKAR can u show me how because I'm new in ios please

Comment: Show this link here is a solution for next previous button

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591792/how-to-get-keyboard-with-next-previous-and-done-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate and the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method. Inside you can get the tag of the `textfield` passed in argument and direct to another one based on this information.

To have the delegate working you have to set delegate property of sender (textfield) to be the receiver (e.g. your view controller)

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

or do it in the storyboard ([here is some storyboard hints](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection)). Your view controller then needs to specify this delegate as follows (in the "h" file):

```
@interface MyViewController:UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

and then in the "m" file

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textfield{
    if([textfield tag] == 1)
    {
        //pass focus to next textfield
        [self.nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        //remove focus from current textfield
        [textfield resignFirstResponder];//
    }
    return YES;//YES if textfield should implement its default behaviour
}
```

Comment: I'm writing this method in my view controller nothing is changing

Comment: Have you set `delegate` on the textfields to point to your view controller?

Comment: one more question please if u want to navigate from text field into a button how i can do it ?

Comment: I haven't tried it but I guess in the same way as `becomeFirstResponder` of `UIResponder` class is available to `UIButton` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField 
  {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if(textField == _your1stTextField)
       [_your2ndTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

set delegates to all of your text fields and then..

```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
    {
       if (textField == textField1)
       {
         [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
       }
       else if (textField == textField2)
       {
         [textField3 becomeFirstResponder];
       }
       else if textField == textField3)
       { 
         [textField4 becomeFirstResponder]; 
       }    
       .
       .
       .

       [textField resignFirstResponder];

       return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is more dynamic as it works for any number of textFields as long as your superview doesn't have a view with a tag == lastTextField.tag + 1

In viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textField1.delegate    = self;
    self.textField2.delegate    = self;
    ...
    self.lastTextField.delegate = self;

    self.textField1.tag    = 1;
    self.textField2.tag    = 2;
    ...
    self.lastTextField.tag = n;
}
```

Then implement the textFieldDelegate:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];

    if (nextResponder)
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    else
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: any idea if i want to pass from text field to a button using the return button on the keyboard ??

Comment: As shown here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html , UIButton inherits from UIResponder. Haven't tried it, but it should definitely work if your last tagged view is a UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare  at .h

.m set

```
yourTextfieldRef1.delegate=self;
yourTextfieldRef2.delegate=self;
yourTextfieldRef3.delegate=self;
yourTextfieldRef4.delegate=self;
yourTextfieldRef5.delegate=self;
.
.
.
```

set

```
yourTextFieldRef1.tag=1;
yourTextFieldRef2.tag=2;
yourTextFieldRef3.tag=3;
yourTextFieldRef4.tag=4;
yourTextFieldRef5.tag=5;
.
.
.


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
    {
        NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
        // Try to find next responder
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
        if (nextResponder) {
            // Found next responder, so set it.
            [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
        } else {
            // Not found, so remove keyboard.
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Hope it helps you...!