# How to add done button on keyboard on top of keyboard in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uikeyboard

I want to add the **`Done`** button on the top of keyboard on right side in iOS for a textView.Please tell me how can i do that?

[image]

I want to achieve something similar to the above keyboard

Comment: You can use UIToolbar!

Comment: create a custom view then show it in your `keyboardOnScreen` notification method...it comes with the keyboard height too so u know where to place the bar

Comment: How yo use with toolbar

Comment: Above screen is related to IQKeyboardManager please add pod file for the same it will automatically manage like above screenshot. Check this link https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager, for setup

Answer (score 43):

Hope this help :)

```
UIToolbar* keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *flexBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                  target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                  target:self action:@selector(yourTextViewDoneButtonPressed)];
keyboardToolbar.items = @[flexBarButton, doneBarButton];
self.yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;
```

and then add yourTextViewDoneButtonPressed method

```
-(void)yourTextViewDoneButtonPressed
{
    [self.yourTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: How to hide how keyboard?

Comment: @deepakkumar What do you mean? if you want to hide the keyboard, just call a method [self.yourTextView resignFirstResponder];

Comment: If keyboard is hidden then toolbar is not hidden.please tell how to do ?

Comment: I have just made a simple test and it worked fine. http://postimg.org/image/tjxdwj3f3/ http://postimg.org/image/rquh87i8f/

Comment: but tollbar does not go away.wehn keyboard is gone

Comment: Can you take a screenshot from your simulator? Did you test with real device and simulator before?

Answer (score 37):

**Swift 3:**

```
func setDoneOnKeyboard() {
    let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
    keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()
    let flexBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(InsertStatusVC.dismissKeyboard))
    keyboardToolbar.items = [flexBarButton, doneBarButton]
    self.fullNameTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 36):

It can be done using storyboard:

1. Add UITextField to UIViewController view.
2. Add UIToolbar in the first level of UIViewController
3. Add UIBarButtonItem into the UIToolbar.
4. Connect UItoolbar to the code using IBOutlet.
5. Connect UIBarButtonItem to the code using IBAction (as didClick).
6. Make the UITextField will be delegating to UIViewController.
7. In the didClick function end editing (***view.endEditing(true)***)
8. In the delegate function textFieldShouldBeginEditing should be: ***textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar*** and returns ***true***.

[image]

Comment: This is great however I am trying to the same for UITextView ? What needs to be different. I edited what I thought but get Cannot assign value of type UIButtonBarItem! to type UIView

Comment: @adamprocter You should assign toolbar to textView.inputAccessoryView, but not UIButtonBarItem.

Comment: Awesome @Ramis (Y) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 15):

This Solution For **Swift3+**

Add This line To your Project As a ***extension***
Your Problem is solved.

```
  extension UITextField{
        
        @IBInspectable var doneAccessory: Bool{
            get{
                return self.doneAccessory
            }
            set (hasDone) {
                if hasDone{
                    addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
                }
            }
        }
        
        func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
        {
            let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
            doneToolbar.barStyle = .default
            
            let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))
            
            let items = [flexSpace, done]
            doneToolbar.items = items
            doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
            
            self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
        }
        
        @objc func doneButtonAction() {
            self.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        
    }
```

Before ***extension***

[image]

After ***extension***

[image]

Comment: Works for UITextView as well. Thanks!

Comment: Exposing `doneAccessory` getter like this when called will cause an infinite loop
`get{ return self.doneAccessory }`

Comment: @anup-gupta it works great but the only issue I get is this warning `All paths through this function will call itself`on this line `get{`

Answer (score 11):

Solution for **Swift 4** and **Swift 5** using a custom class. You can use this class in your Storyboard and .xib files.

```
class UITextFieldWithDoneButton: UITextField {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    }

    fileprivate func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = .default

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))

        let items = [flexSpace, done]
        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }

    @objc fileprivate func doneButtonAction() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked in Xcode 10.2 with Swift 5.0. Thanks Kirill.

Comment: Very nice solution thanx for sharing !! Works as TextView too :-)

Comment: Nice solution! Best way to avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 7):

This Solution For Swift 4

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   //init toolbar
   let toolbar:UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,  width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
   //create left side empty space so that done button set on right side
   let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:    .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
   let doneBtn: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: “Done”, style: .done, target: self, action: Selector(“doneButtonAction”))
   toolbar.setItems([flexSpace, doneBtn], animated: false)
   toolbar.sizeToFit()
   //setting toolbar as inputAccessoryView
   self.textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
   self.textField2.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}
func doneButtonAction() {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add UIToolBar as custom view that will have UIBarButtonItem as Done button  in it.**

*This is safer and cleaner way to add Done button to any Type of Keyboard. Create UIToolBar add Done Button to it and set inputAccessoryView of any UITextField or UITextView.*
];
      }

**SWIFT 3**

```
var ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard = UIToolbar()
ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard.sizeToFit()
var btnDoneOnKeyboard = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .bordered, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneBtnFromKeyboardClicked))
ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard.items = [btnDoneOnKeyboard]
myTextField.inputAccessoryView = ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard
```

*Function*

```
  @IBAction func doneBtnfromKeyboardClicked (sender: Any) {
     print("Done Button Clicked.")
    //Hide Keyboard by endEditing or Anything you want.
    self.view.endEditing(true)
  }
```

Comment: "Create UIToolbar":  A file in code?  A UIBuilder object?  Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Ramis that allows the keyboard accessory view to be created using the Storyboard is a great strategy. It is 2017 after all! (Sorry, but I do not have enough points to upvote you.)

Let me add a little to the answer (to keep within the SO rules). I have a view with multiple textFields. After implementing each of Ramis' steps I attached the accessoryView to all of the textFields in this way:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
_activeTextField = textField;
[_activeTextField setInputAccessoryView:_iboKeyboardTools];
}
```

So easy compared with implementing all this in code! Just build the accessory view in Storyboard- and attach it again and again!