# Swift resigning TextView from first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate, uitextviewdelegate, resignfirstresponder

I have a TextField and a TextView in my ViewController. The ViewController follows both UITextFieldDelegate and UITextViewDelegate and their delegate methods.

I want to resign the TextField or the TextView from being the first responder when the return button is clicked. 
I implemented `func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) 
func textViewShouldReturn(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)` and  have `textField.resignFirstResponder() + textView.resignFirstResponder()` in the corresponding `ShouldReturn` method.

When I click the return button, the TextField resigns successfully and the keyboard hides away; in the case of the TextView, the return button simply adds a new line to the TextView; the `textViewShouldReturn(_:)` doesn't get called at all.

Can someone please explain the difference between `textFieldShouldReturn(_:)` and  `textViewShouldReturn(_:)` and how can I resign the TextView from being the first responder?

Thanks

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var date: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var noteText: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    date.delegate = self
    noteText.delegate = self
}


//MARK: UITextViewDelegate

func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
}

}
```

Comment: You can use return button for TextFields not the TextView

Comment: Create a gesture or a function to it and you'll be fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a trick to resign textview.

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Make sure to set your ViewController as textview's delegate

Comment: Thanks. Then what is textViewShouldReturn(_:) and when should it be used?

Comment: There is no textViewShouldReturn(_:) in UITextViewDelegate functions https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to add toolbar over textview keyboard to resign keyboard as user may want to add new line, so that functionality should remain same.

[How to add done button on keyboard on top of keyboard in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260592/how-to-add-done-button-on-keyboard-on-top-of-keyboard-in-ios)