# How to get iOS 8.3 emoji keyboard height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8.3

I can handle two events: when keyboard shows and when keyboard hides.
Everything worked fine in iOS 8.2 and older.

But how to handle event when you change your keyboard language? When you change the english keyboard to the emoji keyboard, the height of emoji keyboard (in ios 8.3) is bigger and it hides the content.

Or maybe you have a solution how to control iOS 8.3 emoji keyboard height?
[image]

Comment: Check out `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`/`UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification`. These are fired each time the keyboard frame changes, irrespective of the fact whether keyboard is hiding or not. For example, changing keyboard types (ascii/emoji) or toggling predictive text bar above the keyboard.

Comment: OK. Let me update my Xcode and simulators and, i'll give you an optimized working solution. Give me an hour or so.

Answer (score 13):

OK. So looking at my old code, I remembered, I *do not* use 2 observers (`UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`/`UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`). I use a single observer (`UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`), that is fired of each event: Keyboard hiding, keyboard showing, keyboard changing frame.

In my case, the text box and send button are in nested in a `UIView` and this is view is added in the `view` of the `UIViewController`, above everything else.

I add the observer in `viewDidAppear` and remove the observer in `viewWillDisappear`.(to avoid any notification firing when view is not active).

The above information is not necessary for your case, just added it for information sake. Relevant code is as follows:

**ADD OBSERVER:**

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
}
```

**HANDLE NOTIFICATION:**

```
- (void) keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSDictionary* notificationInfo = [notification userInfo];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[[notificationInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]
                          delay:0
                        options:[[notificationInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]
                     animations:^{

                         CGRect frame = self.textViewContainer.frame;
                         frame.origin.y = keyboardFrame.origin.y - frame.size.height;
                         self.textViewContainer.frame = frame;

                     } completion:nil];
}
```

You might have to make a few adjustments to the `frame.origin.y...` line for correct calculations. I don't know whether you have a `UITabBarController` or any bars at the bottom. The safest bet here would be:

```
frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardFrame.size.height - X;
```

Where `X` is 0 if your VC covers the whole screen. If not, use the heights of any bottom bars.

Comment: The layout constraints will need updating in that case.

Comment: While remus provided a correct answer as well, this one is correct and easier to implement / less code. Works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, but how does it dismiss the Keyboard afterwards.  I enabled tap gestures to dismiss and it still stays right above where the keyboard used to be....can you please help me?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Just replace UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey with UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey . :-)

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that the emoji keyboard is the same hight as the standard keyboard with suggested text enabled.

To properly determine keyboard height and adjust your view, add these observers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

Then I use the following methods to animate the keyboard adjustment. Really all you need is the `keyboardBounds` object, but if you happen to be using AutoLayout, this is how you'd do it:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self scrollControlBarTo:notification up:YES];
}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self scrollControlBarTo:notification up:NO];
}

- (void)scrollControlBarTo:(NSNotification *)notification up:(BOOL)up
{
    [_keyboardControlsBar layoutIfNeeded];
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSNumber *number = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    double duration = [number doubleValue];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardBounds];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
                         _keyboardControlsBarBottomConstraint.constant = (up) ? keyboardBounds.size.height : 0;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to determine the keyboard animation time too?? That would be the perfect!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419221/what-is-the-iphones-default-keyboard-animation-rate - updated my answer to include the relevant bits.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957476/ios-7-keyboard-animation for discussion on iOS 7's undocumented animation curve for keyboard animations.

Comment: Nice one @jszumski - updated answer with what appears to be the simplest implementation of that.

Answer (score 0):

Code above but in **swift**:

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}
```

...

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification?) {

let notificationInfo = notification?.userInfo

let keyboardFrame = notificationInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.cgRectValue

UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval((notificationInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue ?? 0.0), delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: (notificationInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.intValue ?? 0), animations: {

    let frame = self.textViewContainer.frame


     frame.origin.y = (keyboardFrame?.origin.y ?? 0.0) - frame.size.height
        self.textViewContainer.frame = frame

    })
}
```