# Getting height of Emoji keyboard IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

The keyboard info dictionary is returning incorrect numbers for the emoji keyboard height. If I click on the textfield it animates up the normal keyboard fine but when i click on the emoji's it still thinks the height is the standard keyboard. Why? And is there a way to get the alternate (emoji) keyboard height programatically. The constant 37 is a terrible hack that I put in to get it to work.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (!IS_SHOWING_KEYBOARD)   {
        IS_SHOWING_KEYBOARD=YES;

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
        CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
        keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        self.commentTopLayout.constant -= keyboardSize.height;
        self.commentBottomLayout.constant -= keyboardSize.height;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];

    } else { //move him down, then up again. //clicked on emojis
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
        CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
        keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        self.commentTopLayout.constant += keyboardSize.height;
        self.commentBottomLayout.constant += keyboardSize.height;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];



        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        self.commentTopLayout.constant -= keyboardSize.height+37;
        self.commentBottomLayout.constant -= keyboardSize.height+37;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];



    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926144/how-to-get-ios-8-3-emoji-keyboard-height

Comment: @Dejan Skledar I'm using the same solution as them and as far as I can tell it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Just replace `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` .  :-)